# Using multiple services or multiple repositories within service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, domain-driven-design

Imagine we have two entities, `EntityA` and `EntityB`. Both entities have a repository to query the database, `EntityARepository` and `EntityBRepository`. There are also services for both of them, `EntityAService` and `EntityBService`.

Now there is a method in the `EntityBService`, which also needs to use `EntityA`. What would be the right way of doing this?

- Should the `EntityBService` use the `EntityARepository` directly?
- Should the `EntityBService` use the `EntityAService`?

I could see how using the repository directly might be very convenient, but also it seems to get kind of messy when having not only two entities.

Is there common design pattern around this topic or recommendations?

Answer (score 13):

TLDR; it depends!

If you're trying to follow Domain Driven Design, I think it's a good idea to differentiate `service` and `repository`. There are different definitions which may differ in details but I'll stick to Martin Fowler's one for [Repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

> (...) A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection. (...)

and for [service](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html):

> A Service Layer defines an application's boundary [Cockburn PloP] and its set of available operations from the perspective of interfacing client layers. **It encapsulates the application's business logic, controlling transactions and coor-dinating responses in the implementation of its operations.**

It is worth pointing out that `service` isn't just `repository` + business logic. For most simple scenarios `repository` just wraps up accessing single database, but for advanced scenarios creating single entity may require accesing multiple databases, so `repository` role is to remove this woffle from `service` layer.

And here is what you could come up with:

1. Use `EntityARepository` directly in `EntityBService` if what you're trying to do is just fetching `EntityA` without any business logic related to `EntityA`. Here is a simple example:

> `EntityBService` performs operation on `EntityB`, but it depends on purely `EntityA` state.

2. Use `EntityAService` in `EntityBService` if requesting `EntityA` involves some business logic related to `EntityA`. Here is a simple example:

> `EntityBService` performs operation on `EntityB` and `EntityA` and later needs to be created if it doesn't exist - creation involves a business logic like checking is it allowed (e.g. based on user role).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there common design pattern around this topic or recommendations?

One common practice is to avoid changing entities that are stored in different places in the same transaction.  One way to ensure that you never do that is to have only one entity active in any transaction.

So we might reasonably have entityA, and a *copy* of the information we need from B.  Or we might have entityB, and a copy of the information we need from A.

For use cases where we aren't changing either entity, we can just use copies of the data.

In the case where we are using `entityA` and `recent-copy-of-B`, we know that entityA comes from a repository.  Where does `recent-copy-of-B` come from?  Well, it comes from an abstraction that looks something like a repository, except (a) it fetches values, rather than entities and (b) it is read only.

`recent-copy-of-B` looks something like a DTO.  And while you might use the same one everywhere, it is actually safe (because values are immutable) to create specialized versions for different use cases.